# How to SUBTRACT TIMESTAMP in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to subtract the followings TIMESTMAP in BigQuery, and get the following result:

```
02/01/2020 20:30:20 - 02/01/2020 20:26:07 = 00:04:13
```

The output format must be in HH:MM:SS

I've tried to use the `TIMESTAMP_DIFF` function but without success.

Do you have any suggetions how to do it?

Comment: Can you show us how did you try ? The code... Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
select time_add(time(0, 0, 0),
                interval timestamp_diff(ts1, ts2, second) second
               )
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this:

```
SELECT 
    time(
       TIMESTAMP_SECONDS
          (timestamp_diff(
            PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y %T','02/01/2020 20:30:20'),
            PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y %T','02/01/2020 20:26:07')
           ,SECOND)
          ))
```